# DBCC CHECKIDENT on a temporary table throwing permissions error for wrong user

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, permissions, temp-tables

I'm logged into a SQL Server 2005 database as a non-sa user, 'bhk', that is a member of the 'public' server role only. The following code tries to execute within a stored procedure called by user 'bhk'. This line of code...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #Table1
DBCC CHECKIDENT('#Table1', RESEED, @SequenceNumber) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

causes this error...

> User 'guest' does not have permission
>   to run DBCC CHECKIDENT for object
>   '#Table1__00000000007F'.

I'm aware of the permissions required to run DBCC CHECKIDENT...
***Caller must own the table***, or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.

So I have two questions:

1. Since 'bhk' is calling a stored
   procedure that creates a temporary
   table, shouldn't 'bhk' be the owner
   and be allowed to run DBCC
   CHECKIDENT?
2. Why does the error
       message return that user 'guest'
       doesn't have permission?  To my knowledge, I'm not
       logged in as 'guest'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution, that may work if you need to re-seed with a sequence number of more than 1.

```
TRUNCATE #Table1

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Table1 ON

INSERT INTO #Table1 (TableID) -- This is your primary key field
VALUES (@SequenceNumber - 1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Table1 OFF

DELETE FROM #Table1
```

What this is doing is to set the IDENTITY_INSERT on your temporary table, to allow you to add a row with an explicit ID. You can then delete this row, but further inserts should start from the last sequence number.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

> "Caller must own the table, or be a
>   member of the sysadmin fixed server
>   role, the db_owner fixed."

So (if it's not a bug), according to [Lieutenant Columbo's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo) impeccable logic, each of the premisses must be false. That means, **the caller does not own the table,** even if he created it.

In fact, it seems that all objects created in tempd **are owned by dbo** by default. You can examine it, if you do following in Query Analyzer:

1. Connect to *your database* using the low-permission user.
2. Execute: `CREATE TABLE #NotMyTable (TestID int identity)`
3. Connect to *tempdb* of the same SQL Server **as dbo**
4. Execute: `SELECT user_name(uid) FROM sysobjects WHERE name LIKE '#NotMyTable%'`

You'll see that dbo is the owner of the temporary table.

**So, what could be a solution?**

(Foreword: *I don't like that kind of manipulation, but the intellectual stimulus is driving me... ;-)*  )

So, you could write another stored procedure which updates the UID in sysobjects of the tempdb to the value of your user (*shiver!*). I tested it only in Query Analyzer. After the Update I could execute your DBCC CHECKIDENT command.

Comment: While this would probably work, I agree with not liking that kind of manipulation.

Comment: What a marvellous comment. It shines due to its wit.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by fully qualifying the tempdb table.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT([tempdb..#Table1], RESEED, @SequenceNumber) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Comment: I'm still receiving permission issues even when fully qualifying.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution to doing the TRUNCATE and CHECKIDENT commands would be to simply drop and re-create your temporary table. E.g.

```
DROP TABLE #Table1

CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
   ....
)
```

This may not be the most efficient solution though.

Comment: You are correct. However, in my situation, the goal is to reset the identity column to something other than 1.  Drop/Create would only reset the column to 1 and doesn't seem to allow variables as a value for the IDENTITY SEED parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this. The answer I came to was to give the relevant account the permissions in the tempdb database where, apparantly, these tables were created.

Comment: I solved this problem by logging in as sa and checking the login I was using to make sure that it had a user mapped in tempdb which had membership in ddladmin