# 'guest' does not have permission to run DBCC CHECKIDENT for object '#TempExtractTableSellIn

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

```
IF  OBJECT_ID(N'TempDb..#TempExtractTableSellIn',N'U') IS NOT NULL  
DROP Table  Tempdb.#TempExtractTableSellIn  
            
 -- Create Temp Table to Hold the delta data while asssgining ISDeleted and PlanCastTransactiionID   
  CREATE TABLE #TempExtractTableSellIn  
       (  
        [PlanCastTransactionID]  [int]  IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,  
        [FiscalMonthId]    [smallint] NOT NULL,  
        [OriginalBillingMonthId] [smallint] NOT NULL,  
        [RestatementVersionID]  [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
        [SubsidiaryId]    [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
        [SalesTeamId]               [int]       NOT NULL,  
        [ChannelID]     [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
        [ProductFamilyID]   [int]  NOT NULL,  
        [DataSourceId]    [smallint] NOT NULL,  
        [CustomerGroupingId]  [tinyint] NULL,  
        [RevenueStreamID]   [int]  NOT NULL,  
        [LicenseTypeId]    [int]  NOT NULL,  
        [BundleStatusID]   [smallint] NOT NULL,  
        [CurrencyId]    [tinyint] NOT NULL,  
        [RestatementVersioncode] [varchar](4)NOT NULL,  
        [SubsidiaryCode]   [char](3) NOT NULL,  
        [ChannelCode]    [char](3) NOT NULL,  
        [ProductFamilyCode]   [char](5) NOT NULL,  
        [ReportingPricingLevelId]   [smallint] NOT NULL,  
        [DataSourceCode]   [char](5) NOT NULL,  
        [ReportedOrganizationID] [nvarchar](36)NOT NULL,  
        [CustomerGroupingCode]  [char](2) NULL,  
        [RevenueStreamCode]   [char](5) NOT NULL,  
        [SubSegmentID]    [int]  NOT NULL,  
        [LicenseTypeCode]   [char](5) NOT NULL,  
        [CurrencyCode]    [char](3) NOT NULL,  
        [Licenses]     [numeric](16, 6) NULL,  
        [BilledAmount]    [Money]  NULL,  
        [BilledAmountLC]   [Money]  NULL,  
        [BilledAmountCD]   [Money]  NULL,  
        [AdjustedAmount]   [Money]  NULL,  
        [AdjustedAmountLC]   [Money]  NULL,  
        [AdjustedAmountCD]   [Money]  NULL,  
        [BudgetCOGS]    [Money]  NULL,  
        [BudgetCOGSLC]    [Money]  NULL,  
        [BudgetCOGSCD]    [Money]  NULL,  
        [ISDeleted]     [BIT]  DEFAULT 0  
       )  
             
        -----------------------Store PROCESSHISTORY Start-----------------------------  
      SELECT @Action = 'Create',@Mode = '',@Object = '#TempExtractTableSellIn',@ObjectType = 'T'  
        ,@Rows = NULL,@Status = 'Run'  
        ,@LogMsg = 'Create Temporary table to hold the Delta Data for: '+@ExtractSellIn  , @TaskName = NULL   
                                                                    
      EXECUTE Staging.StoreProcessHistory   
        @Process = @SP  
        ,@Status  = @Status  
        ,@Mode    = @Mode    
        ,@Object  = @Object  
        ,@ObjectType = @ObjectType  
        ,@Action = @Action  
        ,@Comment = @LogMsg  
        ,@Debug   = @Debug  
        ,@TaskName = @TaskName  
        ,@WorkFlowId = @WorkFlowId  
        ,@ParentTaskId = @TaskId   
        ,@RunId = @RunId  
        -----------------------Store PROCESSHISTORY END-----------------------------   
  
         
       /*INSERT Values from the Rollup table for new records   */  
       SELECT @MaxPlanCastTranID= COALESCE(MAX(PlancastTransactionID)+1,1) FROM [Outbound].MSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn WITH (NOLOCK)    
             
       DBCC CHECKIDENT(#TempExtractTableSellIn,RESEED,@MaxPlanCastTranID)  
                                      
       INSERT INTO #TempExtractTableSellIn WITH (TABLOCK)   
       SELECT    
        RS.[FiscalMonthId]  
        ,RS.[OriginalBillingMonthId]  
        ,RS.[RestatementVersionID]  
        ,RS.[SubsidiaryId]  
        ,RS.[SalesTeamId]  
        ,RS.[ChannelID]  
        ,RS.[ProductFamilyID]  
        ,RS.[DataSourceId]  
        ,ISNULL(RS.[CustomerGroupingId],0)   
        ,RS.[RevenueStreamID]  
        ,RS.[LicenseTypeId]  
        ,RS.[BundleStatusID]  
        ,RS.[CurrencyId]  
        ,RS.[RestatementVersioncode]  
        ,RS.[SubsidiaryCode]  
        ,RS.[ChannelCode]  
        ,RS.[ProductFamilyCode]  
        ,RS.[ReportingPricingLevelId]  
        ,RS.[DataSourceCode]  
        ,RS.[ReportedOrganizationID]  
        ,RS.[CustomerGroupingCode]  
        ,RS.[RevenueStreamCode]  
        ,RS.[SubSegmentID]  
        ,RS.[LicenseTypeCode]  
        ,RS.[CurrencyCode]  
        ,RS.[Licenses]  
        ,RS.[BilledAmount]  
        ,RS.[BilledAmountLC]  
        ,RS.[BilledAmountCD]  
        ,RS.[AdjustedAmount]  
        ,RS.[AdjustedAmountLC]  
        ,RS.[AdjustedAmountCD]  
        ,RS.[BudgetCOGS]  
        ,RS.[BudgetCOGSLC]  
        ,RS.[BudgetCOGSCD]  
        ,0 AS ISdeleted  
   
       FROM     
        [Outbound].RollUpMSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn  RS  
        LEFT JOIN [Outbound].MSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn MSS   
         ON RS.[FiscalMonthId] = MSS.[FiscalMonthId]    AND  
             RS.[OriginalBillingMonthId] = MSS.[OriginalBillingMonthId] AND  
          RS.[RestatementVersionID]= MSS.[RestatementVersionID] AND  
          RS.[SubsidiaryID]= MSS.[SubsidiaryID]     AND  
          RS.[SalesTeamId]= MSS.[SalesTeamId]     AND  
          RS.[ChannelID]=MSS.[ChannelID]       AND  
          RS.[ProductFamilyID]= MSS.[ProductFamilyID]   AND  
          RS.[DataSourceID]= MSS.[DataSourceID]     AND  
          ISNULL(RS.[CustomerGroupingId],0) =ISNULL(MSS.[CustomerGroupingId],0) AND   
          RS.[RevenueStreamID] = MSS.[RevenueStreamID]   AND  
          RS.[LicenseTypeID]= MSS.[LicenseTypeID]     AND  
          RS.[BundleStatusId]= MSS.[BundleStatusId]   AND     
          RS.[CurrencyID]= MSS.[CurrencyID]     AND  
          RS.[ReportingPricingLevelId]= MSS.[ReportingPricingLevelId] AND  
          RS.[ReportedOrganizationID] = MSS.[ReportedOrganizationID] AND  
          RS.[SubsegmentId]=  MSS.[SubsegmentId]   
            
       WHERE  
        MSS.FiscalMonthId IS NULL  
  
       SELECT @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT  
        
   /* SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.  */  
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tempdb. #TempExtractTableSellIn ON   
  
         /*INSERT Values from the base table if already exists   */  
            
       INSERT INTO #TempExtractTableSellIn WITH (TABLOCK)  
       (  
        [PlanCastTransactionID] ,  
        [FiscalMonthId],  
        [OriginalBillingMonthId],  
        [RestatementVersionID],  
        [SubsidiaryId],  
        [SalesTeamId],  
        [ChannelID],  
        [ProductFamilyID],  
        [DataSourceId],  
        [CustomerGroupingId],  
        [RevenueStreamID],  
        [LicenseTypeId],  
        [BundleStatusID],  
        [CurrencyId],  
        [RestatementVersioncode],  
        [SubsidiaryCode],  
        [ChannelCode],  
        [ProductFamilyCode],  
        [ReportingPricingLevelId],  
        [DataSourceCode],  
        [ReportedOrganizationID],  
        [CustomerGroupingCode] ,  
        [RevenueStreamCode],  
        [SubSegmentID],  
        [LicenseTypeCode],  
        [CurrencyCode],  
        [Licenses] ,  
        [BilledAmount],  
        [BilledAmountLC],  
        [BilledAmountCD],  
        [AdjustedAmount] ,  
        [AdjustedAmountLC],  
        [AdjustedAmountCD] ,  
        [BudgetCOGS] ,  
        [BudgetCOGSLC] ,  
        [BudgetCOGSCD],  
        [ISDeleted]   
       )  
       SELECT   
        MSS.[PlanCastTransactionID]  
        ,ISNULL(RS.[FiscalMonthId] ,MSS.[FiscalMonthId])  
        ,ISNULL(RS.[OriginalBillingMonthId] ,MSS.[OriginalBillingMonthId])  
             ,ISNULL(RS.[RestatementVersionID],MSS.[RestatementVersionID])  
            ,ISNULL(RS.[SubsidiaryId],MSS.[SubsidiaryId])  
        ,ISNULL(RS.[SalesTeamId],MSS.[SalesTeamId])  
            ,ISNULL(RS.[ChannelID],MSS.[ChannelID])  
               ,ISNULL(RS.[ProductFamilyID],MSS.[ProductFamilyID])  
                      ,ISNULL(RS.[DataSourceId], MSS.[DataSourceId])  
                      ,ISNULL(ISNULL(RS.[CustomerGroupingId],MSS.[CustomerGroupingId]),0)  
                      ,ISNULL(RS.[RevenueStreamID],MSS.[RevenueStreamID])  
                       ,ISNULL(RS.[LicenseTypeId],MSS.[LicenseTypeId])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[BundleStatusID], MSS.[BundleStatusID])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[CurrencyId],MSS.[CurrencyId])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[RestatementVersioncode],MSS.[RestatementVersioncode])  
                      ,ISNULL(RS.[SubsidiaryCode],MSS.[SubsidiaryCode])  
                      ,ISNULL(RS.[ChannelCode],MSS.[ChannelCode])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[ProductFamilyCode],MSS.[ProductFamilyCode])  
                       ,ISNULL(RS.[ReportingPricingLevelId],MSS.[ReportingPricingLevelId])  
                      ,ISNULL(RS.[DataSourceCode],MSS.[DataSourceCode])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[ReportedOrganizationID],MSS.[ReportedOrganizationID])  
                      ,ISNULL(RS.[CustomerGroupingCode],MSS.[CustomerGroupingCode])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[RevenueStreamCode],MSS.[RevenueStreamCode])  
                    ,ISNULL(RS.[SubSegmentID],MSS.[SubSegmentID])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[LicenseTypeCode], MSS.[LicenseTypeCode])  
                    ,ISNULL(RS.[CurrencyCode],MSS.[CurrencyCode])  
                    ,ISNULL(RS.[Licenses],MSS.[Licenses])  
                       ,ISNULL(RS.[BilledAmount],MSS.[BilledAmount])  
                    ,ISNULL(RS.[BilledAmountLC],MSS.[BilledAmountLC])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[BilledAmountCD],MSS.[BilledAmountCD])  
                       ,ISNULL(RS.[AdjustedAmount],MSS.[AdjustedAmount])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[AdjustedAmountLC],MSS.[AdjustedAmountLC])  
                       ,ISNULL(RS.[AdjustedAmountCD],MSS.[AdjustedAmountCD])  
                    ,ISNULL(RS.[BudgetCOGS],MSS.[BudgetCOGS])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[BudgetCOGSLC],MSS.[BudgetCOGSLC])  
                     ,ISNULL(RS.[BudgetCOGSCD], MSS.[BudgetCOGSCD])  
                    ,CASE WHEN RS.FiscalMonthId IS NULL THEN   1 ELSE  0 END AS ISdeleted   
       FROM     
        [Outbound].RollUpMSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn  RS  
        RIGHT JOIN [Outbound].MSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn MSS   
         ON RS.[FiscalMonthId] = MSS.[FiscalMonthId] AND  
          RS.[OriginalBillingMonthID] = MSS.[OriginalBillingMonthID] AND  
            RS.[RestatementVersionID]= MSS.[RestatementVersionID] AND  
          RS.[SubsidiaryID]= MSS.[SubsidiaryID] AND  
          RS.[SalesTeamID]= MSS.[SalesTeamID] AND  
          RS.[ChannelID]=MSS.[ChannelID] AND  
          RS.[ProductFamilyID]= MSS.[ProductFamilyID] AND  
          RS.[DataSourceID]= MSS.[DataSourceID] AND  
          ISNULL(RS.[CustomerGroupingId],0) =ISNULL(MSS.[CustomerGroupingId],0) AND   
          RS.[RevenueStreamID] = MSS.[RevenueStreamID]  AND  
          RS.[LicenseTypeID]= MSS.[LicenseTypeID] AND  
          RS.[BundleStatusId]= MSS.[BundleStatusId] AND     
          RS.[CurrencyID]= MSS.[CurrencyID] AND  
          RS.[ReportingPricingLevelId]= MSS.[ReportingPricingLevelId] AND  
          RS.[ReportedOrganizationID] = MSS.[ReportedOrganizationID] AND  
          RS.[SubsegmentId]=  MSS.[SubsegmentId]  
        WHERE             
         (ISNULL(RS.[Licenses],0) <>ISNULL(MSS.[Licenses],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[BilledAmount],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[BilledAmount],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[BilledAmountLC],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[BilledAmountLC],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[BilledAmountCD],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[BilledAmountCD],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[AdjustedAmount],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[AdjustedAmount],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[AdjustedAmountLC],0)<> ISNULL(MSS.[AdjustedAmountLC],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[AdjustedAmountCD],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[AdjustedAmountCD],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[BudgetCOGS],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[BudgetCOGS],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[BudgetCOGSLC],0)<>ISNULL(MSS.[BudgetCOGSLC],0)  
         OR ISNULL(RS.[BudgetCOGSCD],0)<> ISNULL(MSS.[BudgetCOGSCD],0))  
         OR RS.FiscalMonthId IS NULL  
                                              
        /* SET IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF.  */  
       SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tempdb. #TempExtractTableSellIn OFF   
            
       SELECT @RowCount =@RowCount +@@ROWCOUNT   
            
                         -----------------------Store PROCESSHISTORY Start-----------------------------  
       SELECT @Action = 'Insert',@Mode = '',@Object ='#TempExtractTableSellIn',@ObjectType = 'T'  
                 ,@Rows =@RowCount ,@Status = 'END'  
                 ,@LogMsg = 'Inserted Delta data into Temp table:Tempdb.#TempExtractTableSellIn for '+@ExtractSellIn    
                 ,@TaskName = NULL        
                             
       EXECUTE Staging.StoreProcessHistory   
          @Process = @SP  
          ,@Status  = @Status  
                  ,@Mode    = @Mode    
                      ,@Object  = @Object  
                                        ,@ObjectType = @ObjectType  
                                        ,@Action = @Action  
                                        ,@Comment = @LogMsg  
                                        ,@Debug   = @Debug  
                                        ,@TaskName = @TaskName  
                                        ,@WorkFlowId = @WorkFlowId  
                                        ,@ParentTaskId = @TaskId   
                                        ,@RunId = @RunId  
                      -----------------------Store PROCESSHISTORY END-----------------------------   
                                  
  
  
  
  
            
             
    
       /*The Extract table is truncated and reloaded every time a new extract is created and the Most recent iteration can be found in  
       'PriorIterationExtract%' tables*/  
            
            
       TRUNCATE TABLE [Outbound].ExtractMSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn  
             
               -----------------------Store PROCESSHISTORY Start-----------------------------  
        SELECT @Action = 'Insert',@Mode = '',@Object = 'ExtractMSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn',@ObjectType = 'T'  
           ,@Rows = NULL,@Status = 'Start'  
                                            ,@LogMsg = 'Starting insertion of records from Temp table to Extract table: '+@ExtractSellIn   , @TaskName = NULL   
                                                                    
       EXECUTE Staging.StoreProcessHistory   
              @Process = @SP  
              ,@Status  = @Status  
              ,@Mode    = @Mode    
              ,@Object  = @Object  
              ,@ObjectType = @ObjectType  
              ,@Action = @Action  
              ,@Comment = @LogMsg  
              ,@Debug   = @Debug  
              ,@TaskName = @TaskName  
              ,@WorkFlowId = @WorkFlowId  
              ,@ParentTaskId = @TaskId   
              ,@RunId = @RunId  
               -----------------------Store PROCESSHISTORY END-----------------------------  
                    
       INSERT INTO  [Outbound].ExtractMSSalesBudgetRevenueSellIn WITH (TABLOCK)  
        ([IterationID]  
                     ,[PlanCastTransactionID]   
                     ,[FiscalMonthId]  
        ,[OriginalBillingMonthID]  
                     ,[RestatementVersionID]  
                     ,[SubsidiaryId]  
        ,[SalesTeamId]  
                          ,[ChannelID]  
                          ,[ProductFamilyID]  
                            ,[DataSourceId]  
                           ,[CustomerGroupingId]  
                          ,[RevenueStreamID]  
                          ,[LicenseTypeId]  
                           ,[BundleStatusID]  
                           ,[CurrencyID]  
                           ,[RestatementVersioncode]  
                             ,[SubsidiaryCode]  
                                ,[ChannelCode]  
                                ,[ProductFamilyCode]  
                                ,[ReportingPricingLevelId]  
                                ,[DataSourceCode]  
                                ,[ReportedOrganizationID]  
                                ,[CustomerGroupingCode]  
                                ,[RevenueStreamCode]  
                                ,[SubSegmentID]  
                                ,[LicenseTypeCode]  
                                ,[CurrencyCode]  
                                ,[Licenses]  
                                ,[BilledAmount]  
                                ,[BilledAmountLC]  
                                ,[BilledAmountCD]  
                                ,[AdjustedAmount]  
                                ,[AdjustedAmountLC]  
                                ,[AdjustedAmountCD]  
                                ,[BudgetCOGS]  
                                ,[BudgetCOGSLC]  
                                ,[BudgetCOGSCD]  
                                ,[IsDeleted])  
       SELECT   
                                    @IterationID  
                                ,[PlanCastTransactionID]   
                                ,[FiscalMonthId]  
        ,[OriginalBillingMonthID]  
                                ,[RestatementVersionID]  
                                ,[SubsidiaryId]  
        ,[SalesTeamId]  
                                ,[ChannelID]  
                                ,[ProductFamilyID]  
                                ,[DataSourceId]  
                                ,[CustomerGroupingId]  
                                ,[RevenueStreamID]  
                                ,[LicenseTypeId]  
                                ,[BundleStatusID]  
                                ,[CurrencyID]  
                                ,[RestatementVersioncode]  
                                ,[SubsidiaryCode]  
                                ,[ChannelCode]  
                                ,[ProductFamilyCode]  
                                ,[ReportingPricingLevelId]  
                                ,[DataSourceCode]  
                                ,[ReportedOrganizationID]  
                                ,[CustomerGroupingCode]  
                                ,[RevenueStreamCode]  
                                ,[SubSegmentID]  
                                ,[LicenseTypeCode]  
                                ,[CurrencyCode]  
                                ,[Licenses]  
                                ,[BilledAmount]  
                                ,[BilledAmountLC]  
                                ,[BilledAmountCD]  
                                ,[AdjustedAmount]  
                                ,[AdjustedAmountLC]  
                                ,[AdjustedAmountCD]  
                                ,[BudgetCOGS]  
                                ,[BudgetCOGSLC]  
                                ,[BudgetCOGSCD]  
                                ,[IsDeleted]   
       FROM #TempExtractTableSellIn
```

I am facing issue with DBCC checkident for above Stored Proc in Azure SQL. The error

> User 'guest' does not have permission to run DBCC CHECKIDENT for object '#TempExtractTableSellIn"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DBCC CHECKIDENT on a temporary table throwing permissions error for wrong user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187920/dbcc-checkident-on-a-temporary-table-throwing-permissions-error-for-wrong-user)

Comment: i don't see the point of having identity in that temptable, nor the RESEED "thing", you seem to be inserting the value into identity from another table. Might as well remove the identity attribute altogether

Comment: @siggemannen could you please re-write the stored proc so i could understand it.

Answer (score 0):

From doc:  [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql)

> Permissions
>
> > **Caller must own the schema that contains the table**, or be a member of the  **sysadmin**  fixed server role, the  **db_owner**  fixed database role, or the  **db_ddladmin**  fixed database role.

I tried to run `DBCC CHECKIDENT` on the temporary table of SQL database master database and database.

- When I query on SQL database, I created it got succeed.
- When I query on master database it gave me error similar to you.

As you see in below image:

[image]

So, you can try it in SQL database you created to resolve it.

As per this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831755/is-there-any-alternative-of-dbcc-checkident) answerd by @Maximus alternative for `DBCC CHECKIDENT` as below.

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] ON
INSERT INTO Mytable(ID,name)values (@AutoIncrementvalue-1,'siva')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] OFF
```